# In which chapter of Brahmanda purana is Shri Lalita Sahasranama present?

Tags: scripture, devi, brahmanda-purana, lalita-sahasranama

The Lalita Sahasranama Stotra belongs to the Uttarakhanda (latter part) of the Brahmanda Purana. In which  chapter can I find the work??

Comment: lalita sahasranAmam is part of the lalitOpAkhyAana section of bramhAnDa purANa.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this version](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahmandapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=31) of the Lalita Sahsranama Stotram hosted by the Kamakoti.org, the  Stotram is present in the **2nd chapter** of Uttara Khanda of the Brahmanda Purana. The name of the chapter is **" Shri Lalitaa Rahasya naama Saahasra Stotra Kathanam "**

> Iti **Shri Brahmaanda Puraaney Uttara Khandey**
>
> Shri Hayagreevaagasthya Samvaadey
>
> **Shri Lalitaa Rahasya naama Saahasra Stotra Kathanam Naama
>   Dwiteeyodhyaayah**

**Meaning**

> Thus ends the **2nd chapter named " Sri Lalita Rahasya Nama Sahasra Stotra
>   Kathanam" of the Uttara Khanda of the Brahmanada Purana** which is in
>   the form of a dialogue between Sri Hayagreeva & Sri Agastya.

Comment: My understanding is that Lalitha sahasranama is not found in any existing version of brahmanda purana. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The Lalita Sahasranama from the Brahmanda-Purana resembles the actual Lalita-Sahasranama which is often seen as an individual work, and is famously commentted upon by Bhaskararaya.

The final part of the Brahmanda Purana is also known as the Lalitopakhyana (Lalita Mahatmya) and constitutes chapters 5-44 of the final portion (Uttarabhaga) of the Brahmanda-Purana. The Lalita Sahasranama is based on the last four chapters (41, 42, 43 and 44) of this Lalitopakhyana and incudes a "thousand-syllabled" praise in chapter 43.

According to S. K. Ramachandra Rao:

> The best-known work of his is on Lalita-sahasranama. This popular 
>   text has been constructed on the basis of Lalitopakhyana, which constitutes 
>   the last four chapters, 41 to 44 of Brahmanda-purana. This text recounting 
>   the thousand significant names of Lalita (also called Lalitamba, Parabhattarika, Lalita-tripura-sundari and Rajarajesvari) is in three chapters, 
>   altogether consisting of 320 verses. 
>   [(source)](https://archive.org/details/LalitaArchanaChandrikaRamchandraRaoS.K.KalpatharuRed/page/n17)

On the following links you can read the [Brahmanda-Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana) and the [Lalitopakhyana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya) and the ["thousand-syllabled mantra"](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362985.html).